# How can i add already created file to xampp local host?

Tags: html, localhost

I'm having an website database but i have to add an blog(additional file or web page) to it. when i tried to open it through localhost it just showing the error in page not found . 
So please help me how can i solve this .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Place your file folder in `Xamp -> htocs` then use `localhost/foldername`

Comment: I tried but still it doesn't works